# Ternary operator not working in if or statement

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have if or statement in which I put some of my conditions and a ternary operator. I've noticed that if I put ?: operator my if statement always go false. I'm wondering what causes it, because true condition comes before evaluating ?: operator so therefore it shouldn't even check it.

```
row.number == barcode -> false;
row.eancode == barcode -> true;
row.packageean == barcode -> false;
row.IspackingcodeNull() -> true;


if (row.number == barcode
    || row.eancode == barcode
    || row.packageean == barcode
    || row.IspackingcodeNull() ? false : row.packingcode == barcode
    || row.producerproductcode == barcode
    || row.alternativebarcode1 == barcode)
```

Comment: `|| (row.IspackingcodeNull() ? false : row.packingcode == barcode)`, turnary operator has low priority

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've actually done is this:

```
if 
(
    (
        row.number == barcode
        || row.eancode == barcode
        || row.packageean == barcode
        || row.IspackingcodeNull()
    ) 
    ? false 
    : row.packingcode == barcode || row.producerproductcode == barcode || row.alternativebarcode1 == barcode
)
```

What you want is this:

```
if (row.number == barcode
    || row.eancode == barcode
    || row.packageean == barcode
    || (row.IspackingcodeNull() ? false : row.packingcode == barcode)
    || row.producerproductcode == barcode
    || row.alternativebarcode1 == barcode)
```

Comment: But why if statement is going further after second condition being true?

Comment: @DaumantasDrukteinis Assuming that `row.number == barcode`, `row.eancode == barcode` and `row.packageean == barcode` are all false, then in the first version if `row.IspackingcodeNull()` is false then the body of the `if` won't be entered regardless of the state of the remainder of the comparisons, since they would only be checked if `row.IspackingcodeNull() ` is true.

Comment: If `row.eancode == barcode` then in either case it would not check the remaining conditions - and writing the code either way would make no difference. Are you absolutely sure it's true in the cases where you saw a problem?

Comment: 100% sure,
I wrote short fiddle, take a look https://dotnetfiddle.net/ftdWyV

Comment: @DaumantasDrukteinis Ah sorry, I've added an extra set of parenthesis to show what's happening more clearly. Everything up to the end of `row.IspackingcodeNull())` was considered to be the qualifier for the ternary expression.